# Check String for / against Characters in Python

Tags: python, regex

I need to be able to tell the *difference* between a string that can contain **letters and numbers**, and a string that can contain **numbers, colons and hyphens**.

```
>>> def checkString(s):
...   pattern = r'[-:0-9]'
...   if re.search(pattern,s):
...     print "Matches pattern."
...   else:
...     print "Does not match pattern."

# 3 Numbers seperated by colons. 12, 24 and minus 14
>>> s1 = "12:24:-14"
# String containing letters and string containing letters/numbers.
>>> s2 = "hello"
>>> s3 = "hello2"
```

When I run the `checkString` method on each of the above strings:

```
>>>checkString(s1)
Matches Pattern.
>>>checkString(s2)
Does not match Pattern.
>>>checkString(s3)
Matches Pattern
```

s3 is the only one that doesn't do what I want. I'd like to be able to create a regex that allows numbers, colons and hyphens, but excludes EVERYTHING else (or just alphabetical characters). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

Therefore, I need a regex that would accept:

```
229            // number
187:657        //two numbers
187:678:-765   // two pos and 1 neg numbers
```

and decline:

```
Car          //characters
Car2         //characters and numbers
```

Comment: Do you want to positive-match things that are letters+numbers, or do you not? You state at the beginning matching letters+numbers, but then you say you don't want to match s3 (but you do want to match s2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to match the whole string, not a single character as you do at the moment:

```
>>> re.search('^[-:0-9]+$', "12:24:-14")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01013758>
>>> re.search('^[-:0-9]+$', "hello")
>>> re.search('^[-:0-9]+$', "hello2")
```

To explain regex:

- within square brackets (character class): match digits 0 to 9, hyphen and colon, only once.
- `+` is a quantifier, that indicates that preceding expression should be matched as many times as possible but at least once.
- `^` and `$` match start and end of the string. For one-line strings they're equivalent to `\A` and `\Z`.

This way you restrict content of the whole string to be at least one-charter long and contain any permutation of characters from the character class. What you were doing before hand was to search for a single character from the character class within subject string. This is why `s3` that contains a digit matched.

Comment: Your regex will fail to match on the second string, which they have indicated is not what they want.

Comment: Let's read the question again: *s3 is the only one that doesn't do what I want.* s2 and s3 both are not supposed to match.

Comment: Mm, a bit cryptically phrased I guess. "s3 is the only one that doesn't do what I want" could be interpreted as "the only one I don't want to match".

Comment: @_bravado: to me it was clear from the very beginning :) and my solution evidently works.

Comment: Can I ask what the '^' does? Or could you explain what each of the symbols mean (before/after the square brackets)?

Comment: Why not use .match instead of .search and drop the ^/$ ?

Comment: you would be able to drop only the `^`, not the `$`. and I don't think that it's worth confusion.

Comment: Note that this would also match strings like `"---::::"` with no digits at all.  I think you're looking for something like my answer...

Answer (score 1):

SilentGhost's answer is pretty good, but take note that it would also match strings like `"---::::"` with no digits at all.

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
'^(-?\d+:)*-?\d+$'
```

- `^` Matches the beginning of the line.
- `(-?\d+:)*` Possible - sign, at least one digit, a colon.  That whole pattern 0 or many times.
- `-?\d+` Then the pattern again, at least once, without the colon
- `$` The end of the line

This will better match the strings you describe.

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = r'\A([^-:0-9]+|[A-Za-z0-9])\Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is almost fine; you just need to make it match the whole string.  Also, as a commenter pointed out, you don't really need a raw string (the `r` prefix on the string) in this case.  Voila:

```
def checkString(s):
  if re.match('[-:0-9]+$', s):
    print "Matches pattern."
  else:
    print "Does not match pattern."
```

The '+' means "match one or more of the previous expression".  (This will make checkString return False on an empty string.  If you want True on an empty string, change the '+' to a '*'.)  The '$' means "match the end of the string".

re.match means "the string must match the regular expression starting at the first character"; re.search means "the regular expression can match a sequence anywhere inside the string".

Also, if you like premature optimization--and who doesn't!--note that 're.match' needs to compile the regular expression each time.  This version compiles the regular expression only once:

```
__checkString_re = re.compile('[-:0-9]+$')
def checkString(s):
  global __checkString_re
  if __checkString_re.match(s):
    print "Matches pattern."
  else:
    print "Does not match pattern."
```

Comment: try this: `>>> re.match('[-:0-9]+', "2hello2")`

Comment: Why did you declare the compiled string `global`?  To save space by keeping the function from closing over it?

Comment: steveha: Just to show intent.  The function as written would work fine if that line were removed.

Personally I find the rules regarding when Python automatically looks in module scope for you annoying, so I tend to use "global" more often then most.